# Xamarin InvalidCastException but no cast?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm at a loss as to what is going on here. I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Widget.ImageView' to type 'Android.Widget.EditText'.

I'm not doing such a cast to my knowledge. I have the following code:

`private EditText passwordText;
 passwordText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.passwordText); //error here`

and the following xml:

```
    <EditText
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/passwordText"
    android:text="password"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/HintPassword" />
```

I only receive an error when trying to run my application on an emulator running API 23 but there is no issue when running it on API 19. There is no issue when I run it on my physical device either. Thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you have multiple resolution layouts and thus are loading one  where the `android:id` is the same? Search your solution for `android:id="@+id/passwordText"` and make sure all matching elements are of the `EditText` class.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I checked for another instance and it's the only one. Just in case I changed the name and same thing. I went to my layout file and changed and commented out the only image view I had and now instead it tells me I am unable to convert type EditText to Button. If I try something else I get the same error saying the object cannot convert to the one 2 tags above it.